# YAML::TypedBadConversion<double> yaml-cpp on NTRTsim

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

I am using NASA Tensegrity Robot Toolkit simulator, which uses YAML to build the structure. i have validated my structure from https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator.

It keeps throwing the error of bad conversion on my file while works fine on a pre-installed yaml structure.

This is the terminal window:

`tensegribuntu@TensegritBuntu-VM:~/NTRTsim$ build/yamlbuilder/BuildModel resources/YamlStructures/BaseStructures/SuperBall.yaml
Box Ground
setup graphics
tensegribuntu@TensegritBuntu-VM:~/NTRTsim$ build/yamlbuilder/BuildModel resources/YamlStructures/ZenStructures/30bar.yaml
Box Ground
setup graphics
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<double>'
  what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 0, column 0: bad conversion
Aborted (core dumped)
tensegribuntu@TensegritBuntu-VM:~/NTRTsim$`

Any ideas?

code:

```
nodes:

  top1: [ 04.06 , 109.2 , 0.55 ]
  bottom1: [-4.08 , 103.68 , -8.5]

  top2: [-3.61 , 90.74 ,-2.06 ]
  bottom2: [ 8.29, 96.3 , 4.53 ]

  top3: [ -9.35 , 103.65 , 1.23 ]
  bottom3: [ 1.76 , 109.21 , -3.73 ]

  top4: [ -3.04, 109.3 , -2.78 ]
  bottom4: [ -1.73 , 103.63 , 9.25 ]

  top5: [ 5.74 , 92.49. , 3.68 ]
  bottom5: [ 6.4 , 99.48 , -7.69 ]

  top6: [ 8.29, 103.68, 4.5]
  bottom6: [ 3.59 , 109.24 , 1.91 ]

  top7: [ 0.84 , 109.8 , 4.05 ]
  bottom7: [ 6.81 , 103.67 , -6.47 ]

  top8: [ 3.61 , 102.34 , -9.15 ]
  bottom8: [ -8.29 , 97.64 , -5.28 ]

  top9: [ 9.38 , 100.55 , -3.92]
  bottom9: [-1.74 , 107.44 , -6.68]

  top10: [ 3.03 , 106.65 , -7.04 ]
  bottom10: [1.73 , 93.35 , -7.42 ]

  top11: [ -6.91 , 92.56 , 0.42 ]
  bottom11: [ -0.75 , 99.48 , 10.06 ]

  top12: [ 6.85 , 96.33 , 6.48 ]
  bottom12: [.83 , 90.71, -4.05 ]

  top13: [9.83 ,102.41 , 0.57 ]
  bottom13: [2.53 ,97.62 ,-9.56 ]

  top14: [ 6.56 , 100.5 , 7.68 ]
  bottom14: [5.76  ,107.43  , -3.73 ]

  top15: [ 07.61 , 93.35  , 0.65 ]
  bottom15: [ 7.68 , 106.65, 0.73 ]

  top16: [9.85 ,97.61 ,-0.56 ]
  bottom16: [ 2.52 , 102.37, 9.56 ]

  top17: [ -5.28, 100.53  , 8.64 ]
  bottom17: [ 5.33 , 107.43 , 4.35 ]

  top18: [ 1.67 , 0.53 , 7.48 ]
  bottom18: [ 3.01 , 93.35 , 7.02 ]

  top19: [ 3.56 , 97.57 , 9.2 ]
  bottom19: [ -8.3 , 102.36  , 5.32 ]

  top20: [ -9.87 , 97.61, 0.59 ]
  bottom20: [ -2.47 , 107.47 , 6.36 ]

  top21: [ -5.79 ,93.35 , 5.04 ]
  bottom21: [ 6.62 , 106.64 , 3.9 ]

  top22: [ 7.64 , 97.72 , 6.28 ]
  bottom22: [ -7.6 ,102.35 , -6.26 ]

  top23: [ -0.81 , 100.48 , -10.06 ]
  bottom23: [ -6.87 , 107.45 , -0.4 ]

  top24: [ -5.8, 106.05 , -5.08 ]
  bottom24: [ -6.57 , 106.65 , -3.97 ]

  top25: [ 5.34 , 92.59 , -4.36 ]
  bottom25: [ -5.3 , 99.429 ,-8.66 ]

  top26: [ -4.09 , 96.27 , 8.52 ]
  bottom26: [ 4.09 , 90.73 , -4.9 ]

  top27: [ -1.75 , 92.56, 6.67]
  bottom27: [ 9.38 , 99.43 , 3.88 ]

  top28: [ -1.71 , 96.25  , -9.31 ]
  bottom28: [ -3.03 ,90.7  , 2.79 ]

  top29: [ 1.72 , 90.71 , 3.72 ]
  bottom29: [ -9.35 , 96.31 , -1.26 ]

  top30: [ -9.84 , 99.45 , 2.38 ]
  bottom30: [ -2.47 , 93.63 , -7.47 ]



pair_groups:
 rod:
    - [bottom1,top1]
    - [bottom2,top2]
    - [bottom3,top3]
    - [bottom4,top4]
    - [bottom5,top5]
    - [bottom6,top6]
    - [bottom7,top7]
    - [bottom8,top8]
    - [bottom9,top9]
    - [bottom10,top10]
    - [bottom11,top11]
    - [bottom12,top12]
    - [bottom13,top13]
    - [bottom14,top14]
    - [bottom15,top15]
    - [bottom16,top16]
    - [bottom17,top17]
    - [bottom18,top18]
    - [bottom19,top19]
    - [bottom20,top20]
    - [bottom21,top21]
    - [bottom22,top22]
    - [bottom23,top23]
    - [bottom24,top24]
    - [bottom25,top25]
    - [bottom26,top26]
    - [bottom27,top27]
    - [bottom28,top28]
    - [bottom29,top29]
    - [bottom30,top30]

 string:
    - [top1,bottom3]
    - [top1,top7]
    - [top1,bottom14]

    - [bottom1,bottom9]
    - [bottom1,top23]
    - [bottom1,top24]

    - [top2,bottom12]
    - [top2,bottom28]
    - [top2,bottom30]

    - [bottom2,top5]
    - [bottom2,top15]
    - [bottom2,top25]

    - [top3,top20]
    - [top3,bottom21]
    - [top3,bottom23]

    - [bottom3,top4]
    - [bottom3,bottom9]

    - [top4,bottom6]
    - [top4,bottom23]

    - [bottom4,bottom20]
    - [bottom4,top17 ]
    - [bottom4,top18]

    - [top5,top9]
    - [top5,bottom13]

    - [bottom5,top12]
    - [bottom5,top15]
    - [bottom5,bottom26]

    - [top6,top14]
    - [top6,bottom15]
    - [top6,bottom17]

    - [bottom6,top7]
    - [bottom6,bottom20]

    - [top7,bottom17]

    - [bottom7,top9]
    - [bottom7,top10]
    - [bottom7,bottom14]

    - [top8,top10]
    - [top8,bottom13]
    - [top8,top23]

    - [bottom8,bottom22]
    - [bottom8,bottom24]
    - [bottom8,bottom25]

    - [top9,top13]

    - [bottom9,top10]

    - [bottom10,bottom13]
    - [bottom10,top25]
    - [bottom10,top28]

    - [top11,bottom29 ]
    - [top11,bottom28]
    - [top11,top21] 

    - [bottom11,top19]
    - [bottom11,top26]
    - [bottom11,top17]

    - [top12,bottom18]
    - [top12,bottom27] 

    - [bottom12,top25]
    - [bottom12,bottom26]

    - [top13,bottom15]
    - [top13,top16]

    - [top14,bottom16]
    - [top14,bottom27]

    - [bottom14,bottom15]

    - [top15,top16]

    - [top16,bottom27]

    - [bottom16,top18]
    - [bottom16,top19]

    - [top17,bottom19]

    - [bottom17,top18]

    - [bottom18,top19]
    - [bottom18,top27]

    - [bottom19,bottom21]
    - [bottom19,top22]

    - [top20,top30]
    - [top20,bottom22]

    - [bottom20,bottom21]

    - [top21,top22]
    - [top21,top26]

    - [top22,top30]

    - [bottom22,top24]
    - [bottom22,top20]

    - [top23,bottom25]

    - [bottom23,top24]

    - [bottom24,bottom29]
    - [bottom24,bottom30]

    - [bottom25,top28]

    - [top26,top27]

    - [bottom26,top29]

    - [bottom27,top29]

    - [top28,bottom30]

    - [bottom28,top29]

    - [bottom29,top30]



builders:
  rod:
    class: tgRodInfo
    parameters:
      density: 0.688
      radius: 0.31
      friction: 0.99
      roll_friction: 0.01
      restitution: 0.0
  string:
    class: tgBasicActuatorInfo
    parameters:
      stiffness: 613.0
      damping: 200.0
      pretension: 2452.0
      history: 0
      max_tension: 100000
      target_velocity: 10000
```

Comment: the SUPERball is preinstalled and 30bar is mine

Comment: We can only help you if you show us the content of your YAML file.

Comment: Please don't link to external code, include the code in your question instead. External sources may vanish, and also no-one wants to solve captchas just to see your code.

Comment: posted code. thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`04.06` is not a number in YAML, see [the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804356):

> -? ( 0 | [1-9] [0-9]* )   tag:yaml.org,2002:int
>   -? ( 0 | [1-9] [0-9]* ) ( . [0-9]* )? ( [eE] [-+]? [0-9]+ )?      tag:yaml.org,2002:float

Change it to `4.06`.

The validator cannot help you here since `04.06` is generally a valid scalar; it can be loaded as string. A general YAML validator will always only validate your syntax. It cannot validate whether your structure and types are appropriate for whatever application you use the YAML with.

Comment: that didn't work. I changed a number 75 to 075 in the Superball preinstalled file, that didn't stop it from working.

Comment: @Jin You also have a `92.49.`, a `.83` and a `07.61` in there which may be the culprit.

Comment: It was the `92.49.`!!! Thank you so much!! Ill mention yuo in my Gold medal speech I get to!

Comment: For the future: To find such anomalies, use a tool like [this](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) or [this](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) (latter one is my work) to view the *canonical* representation of the YAML. Then search for `!!str` tags that should be `!!int` / `!!float`.